# Why `fullscreenchange` is not triggered when pressing `F11` in Chrome 116

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, fullscreen

```js
const OnFullScreenChange = () => {
  console.log('test')
}

document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', OnFullScreenChange)
```

Here test is only triggered when calling `document?.requestFullscreen()`
But not when I press `F11`

How to detect `F11` full screen event?